# How to use PSReadline to have bash style cursor movement

Tags: powershell

How can I get these shortcuts with PSReadLine:

ctrl+a : Move to the beginning of the line
ctrl+e : Move to the end of the line
ctrl+w : Delete a word backwards
ctrl+k : Delete all words backwards

Have not seen how to do this with PSReadLine. I mostly just want ctrl+a and ctrl+e I use these constantly in bash and its irritating to have to use home,end on Windows.

Comment: Windows uses Home and End, that's the point of them.  If you want to map non-standard keyboard shortcuts, then look into using Autohotkey or alike.

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote. So this can't be accomplished with psreadline? Is there another way to do this with powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type this to get a list of the current and available keybindings:

```
Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler
```

And then set them with `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler`. Here is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> as an example to get you started:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+a -Function BeginningOfLine
```

You can put these `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler`commands in your $profile so they get run every session.

I'll let you work out the other keybindings for yourself. This is all documented on the [PSReadline page](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine), by the way.